# Return a map of components after adding data without pre initialising it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following where I initialise an empty map.

I then loop over some data to create a map of keys and components.

Is there a way I could do this without having to pre initialize the map

and instead map as follows but just assign the results to a variable

ending up with same results?

It present, I am returning from within the Object.keys just to satisfy an eslint

and the return serves no purpose.

This is what I currently have which works:

```
const benefitTiles = {};
const allBenefits = group.benefits;
Object.keys(group.benefits).map((key) => {
benefitTiles[key] =
    (
    <MyComponent
        data={{
        header: allBenefits[key].title,
        flag: Boolean(allBenefits[key].icon) && {
            text: allBenefits[key].icon,
        },
        image: {
            src: allBenefits[key].img,
        },
        }}
    />
    );
    return benefitTiles;
});
```

Trying to achieve something like this which won't work currently:

```
  const allBenefits = group.benefits;
  const benefitTiles = Object.keys(group.benefits).map((key) => {
    benefitTiles[key] =
      (
        <MyComponent
          data={{
            header: allBenefits[key].title,
            flag: Boolean(allBenefits[key].icon) && {
              text: allBenefits[key].icon,
            },
            image: {
              src: allBenefits[key].img,
            },
          }}
        />
      );
    return benefitTiles;
  });
```

Comment: You can do this in one line using `.reduce`

Comment: it's not to satisfy eslint, but to correctly use `map()`. You are using it as a `forEach()` and discarding the returned array. Also you aren't initializing a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) at all, but an Object.

Comment: @pilchard In this case, would a foreach be the correct way?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Could I get an example for the above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.fromEntries` to construct the object from an array of entries (key-value pairs, in the form of an array) all at once.

```
const benefitTiles = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(group.benefits).map(
        ([key, value]) => [
            key,
            <MyComponent
                data={{
                    header: benefit.title,
                    flag: Boolean(benefit.icon) && {
                        text: benefit.icon,
                    },
                    image: {
                        src: benefit.img,
                    },
                }}
            />
        ]
    )
);
```

That said, I think it's a bit strange to be creating a component (JSX syntax, or `React.createElement`) anywhere other than when rendering - it might make more sense to only call `<MyComponent` later, rather than now, when constructing the object.

Comment: Doing this cos I am repeating about 12 times this same component using external data. Some of these components need to be 2 in a row and some 3 i na row and so on. There is no way to differentiate which component would have how many rows. Bit of hardcoding done to address this. By doing the above, reducing the component creation and just calling the relevant component by key ending up with a 1 liner inside the render block.